# Scripting in Perl/cURL, can't get past HTML-form w/ two submits and click() onload

Tags: html, perl, curl

I'm making a script where a major part of it is to login through a system called Feide. I've used Perl and cURL, and I've managed to actually log in and make a session cookie, but due to the fact that cURL doesn't support Javascript, I have to press a button ("Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the button below once to proceed.") to get to the content of the site I want to access. Unfortunately, the form is weird. When I run my script, it simply redirects me back to the same site, and I don't know why. Here's the HTML:

```
<body onload="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();">

<noscript>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the button below once to proceed.</p> 
</noscript> 

<form method="post" action="https://innsida.ntnu.no/c/portal/login">

<!-- Need to add this element and call click method, because calling submit()
on the form causes failed submission if the form has another element with name or id of submit.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit#Specification -->

    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" />

    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="[very long value]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="https://innsida.ntnu.no" />

        <noscript>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </noscript>
</form>

</body>
```

Maybe there's something I'm missing, but I can't seem to submit this form in a proper manner. Here's my script:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use WWW::Curl::Easy;
    use WWW::Curl::Multi;
    use WWW::Curl::Share;
    use WWW::Curl::Form;
    use DBI;


    my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:feide', '[myusername]', '[mypassword]') || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";


    my $username = $dbh->prepare('SELECT username FROM credentials WHERE id=1');

     my $password = $dbh->prepare('SELECT password FROM credentials WHERE id=1');

     my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy-> new;

     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
     #Make sure redirects don't fuck me
     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
     #Where cookies are saved 
     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
     #Where cookies are read from
     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1");
     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'https://idp.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/feide/login.php?asLen=225&AuthState=_3f669be75024644be95e67ec6845222aefa860db98%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fidp.feide.no%2Fsimplesaml%2Fsaml2%2Fidp%2FSSOService.php%3Fspentityid%3Durn%253Amace%253Afeide.no%253Aservices%253Ano.ntnu.innsida%26cookieTime%3D1456232047%26RelayState%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Finnsida.ntnu.no');

     my $response_body;
     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

    my $retcode = $curl->perform;
    my $checkSession = 0;
    my @split;
    #check if there is a current session
    if($response_body =~ /"AuthState" value="/){
     @split = split /"AuthState" value="/, $response_body;
     my @authState = split /"/, $split[1];

     #make a form for a POST-request
     my $curlf = WWW::Curl::Form->new;
     $checkSession = 1;

     $curlf->formadd("feidename", $username);
     $curlf->formadd("password", $password);
     $curlf->formadd("asLen", "225");
     $curlf->formadd("AuthState", $authState[0]);
     $curlf->formadd("org", "ntnu.no"); 

     $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $curlf);


     $retcode = $curl->perform;
    }




    if ($checkSession){
    @split = ();
    @split = split /"SAMLResponse" value="/, $response_body;
    }
    else{
     my @split = split /"SAMLResponse" value="/, $response_body;
    }

    my @SAML = split /"/, $split[1];

    #Here I try to create a new form, where I add what 
    #I believe to be the correct values. They don't work, 
    #and I get redirected back to the "press the button"-website

    my $noJS = WWW::Curl::Form->new;
    $noJS->formadd("SAMLResponse", $SAML[0]);
    $noJS->formadd("RelayState", "https://innsida.ntnu.no");

    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $noJS);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'https://innsida.ntnu.no/c/portal/login');

    $curl->perform;


    print $response_body, "\n";
```

Naturally, I can't put my username and password to Feide here, so you won't be able to try it out for yourselves. Hopefully someone sees a solution regardless.

I'm posting the entire HTML-code (the output of the script) here at the end, in case someone's interested:

```
     HTTP/1.1 302 Found
     Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 10:35:10 GMT
     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
     X-XSS-Protection: 1
     Pragma: no-cache
     Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
     Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
     Location: https://idp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?SAMLRequest=[removed for security purposes]
     Content-Length: 0

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 10:35:10 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.26
    Content-Length: 7866
    Content-Type: text/html

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>POST data</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();">

<noscript>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the button below once to proceed.</p> 
</noscript> 

<form method="post" action="https://innsida.ntnu.no/c/portal/login">
<!-- Need to add this element and call click method, because calling submit()
on the form causes failed submission if the form has another element with name or id of submit.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit#Specification -->
<input type="submit" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="[ridiculously long value]==" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="https://innsida.ntnu.no" />
            <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </noscript>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If I left out something, let me know, and I'll do my best to provide it.

EDIT: When I turned off Javascript in my browser and copied as cUrl, I got this:

```
curl 'https://innsida.ntnu.no/c/portal/login' 
-H 'Host: innsida.ntnu.no' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: https://idp.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/feide/login.php?asLen=225&AuthState= [removed]https%253A%252F%252Finnsida.ntnu.no' 
-H 'Cookie: COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=nb_NO; JSESSIONID=[removed].innsidaprod01; LFR_SESSION_STATE_111384=[removed]; LFR_SESSION_STATE_10135=[removed] -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data 'SAMLResponse=[long value]&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Finnsida.ntnu.no'
```

Comment: in PHP you would do $inputs=array(); $domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html); foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("form")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("input") as $input){ $inputs[$input->getAttribute("name")]=$input->getAttribute("value");} curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$inputs);

Comment: You have not stated what your problem is. What happens when you submit the form? Did you try to submit the form in a browser, and just copy the fields from that? (network tab, and then Copy as cUrl)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to state the problem in the beginning of the text. When I submit the form, I get redirected back to the same site, with no changes. Edited it, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Did you try to copy the request as cURL in the Network Tab, check that it works from the command line and see that you set all the fields that are being set are set in your script as well?

Comment: @bolav Giving it a try now

Comment: @bolav Had not idea this functionality existed in browsers. Thanks a lot! Should give me some idea of how to solve this.

Comment: Did the curl command work?

Comment: It worked. I'm not sure how it differs from the request in my script, but at least now I have the groundwork to find out ^^

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the form is not validating, and you therefore are redirected to the same form. If they don't have any special kind of scripting protection you should be able to create a valid request by going to the `Network Tab` of `Developer Tools` on your browser, and select `Copy as cURL`. This will give you a list of all options being set on a valid request.

This should help you get past the redirect loop.

Comment: It gave me something more to work with. I updated the post with the request. Thanks a lot.